# Switching between for loop for array printint. Java

Tags: java, arrays, printf

How can i print an array 10 items per row for 20 rows. Then i want to jump to the next array and do the same. After that ask the user for input to continue or not.

Here is a sample output that i have:

```
===================================== After Level 1 Merged ==========================================

 {   129 } {   133 } {   354 } {   425 } {   632 } {   779 } {  1067 } {  1126 } {  1185 } {  1306 }
 {  1373 } {  1384 } {  1472 } {  1607 } {  1731 } {  1756 } {  1854 } {  1907 } {  1982 } {  2029 }
 {    54 } {   225 } {   259 } {   426 } {   449 } {   683 } {   728 } {   911 } {   920 } {  1009 }
 {  1056 } {  1266 } {  1288 } {  1323 } {  1404 } {  1666 } {  1848 } {  1912 } {  1968 } {  1970 }
 {  1997 } {  2021 }

===================================== After Level 2 Merged ==========================================

 {    54 } {   129 } {   133 } {   225 } {   259 } {   354 } {   425 } {   426 } {   449 } {   632 }
 {   683 } {   728 } {   779 } {   911 } {   920 } {  1009 } {  1056 } {  1067 } {  1126 } {  1185 }
 {  1266 } {  1288 } {  1306 } {  1323 } {  1373 } {  1384 } {  1404 } {  1472 } {  1607 } {  1666 }
 {  1731 } {  1756 } {  1848 } {  1854 } {  1907 } {  1912 } {  1968 } {  1970 } {  1982 } {  1997 }
 {  2021 } {  2029 }
```

Here is my code:

```
System.out.printf("\nmy header \n\n", MemberConstant.MERGERSEC);

    for (int i = 0; i < K; i++) {
        for (int j = brds[i].start; j < brds[i].size + brds[i].start; j++) {
            System.out.printf(" {");
            System.out.printf("%6d ", a[j]);
            cnt1++; 
            System.out.printf("}");
            if(cnt1 == 10) {
                System.out.printf("\n");
                mod2++;
                cnt1=0;
            }
        }  
    } 

    cnt1=0;
        System.out.printf("my header\n\n", MemberConstant.MERGERSEC2);

        for (int k = 0; k < K; k++) {
        for (int l = brds[k].start; l < brds[k].size + brds[k].start; l++) {
             System.out.printf(" {");
            System.out.printf("%6d ", b[l]);
            cnt1++; 
            System.out.printf("}");
            if(cnt1 == 10) {
                System.out.printf("\n");
                mod2++;
                cnt1=0; 

            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should have a separate method for printing arrays and another cycle for asking a user. Something like this:

```
private int printArr(ArrayType a, int start, int rows) {
  rows = Math.min(rows, a.length - start);
  cnt1 = 0;
  for (int i = start; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = brds[i].start; j < brds[i].size + brds[i].start; j++) {
            System.out.printf(" {");
            System.out.printf("%6d ", a[j]);
            cnt1++; 
            System.out.printf("}");
            if(cnt1 == 10) {
                System.out.printf("\n");
                mod2++;
                cnt1=0;
            }
        }  
    }
    return start + rows; // current position 
}
```

And for asking users:

```
int aStart = 0;
int bStart = 0;
int rows = 20;
do {
  aStart = printArr(a, aStart, rows);
  bStart = printArr(b, bStart, rows);
  // Ask user somehow
} while (//User wants to continue);
```

Assuming that `brds` and `mod2` also declared somewhere